# S3 CSS assets not loading, but previously did. Why would it stop?

Tags: css, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, static

I've been using S3 to host static websites and I've made changes to the HTML & CSS files and have seen those changes reflected in the past. For some reason I go to do the exact same thing I've done before, change the style of one of my sites, and no change would take place. In-fact after deleting all previous files, the old build was still rendering. I had no version control on that particular bucket.

Content-type is set to 'text/css'.  My file structure is normal with index.html being in the root. My normal steps of creating or updating new or existing sites has not changed, but S3 has for some reason.

When I click on the index.html file and go to the public url link, it reflects all my changes.

My only fix is to add the full url to the style link.

`<link href="https://s3.amazonaws.com/{bucket-name}/css/style.css">`

Does anyone know why this is happening or how to fix it other than adding the http link? If not, I hope my solution helps others for this weird S3 issue. Normally you can just upload your files to a bucket, set the policy and finally enable hosting after stating the root html file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might be due to your browser caching, where it's loading locally stored assets (CSS stylesheet) from a previous time you've visited the URL rather than fetching the new resources in an attempt to speed up load times. There are settings you can change in your browser to determine how long your browser will hold onto cached resources before fetching new ones.

By setting the stylesheet link directly to the s3 bucket URL, it will cause it to fetch the new stylesheet every time the page is loaded, which leads me to believe that caching is the issue here.

**Try clearing your cache and see if it solves the problem.**

[Here is a deeper explanation of the concept with respect to browsers, and a list of commands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Bypass_your_cache) to perform a cache refresh depending on what browser/OS you have!

Comment: That was the issue. Thank you! I found the right command from that link you provided. It worked right away, without having to use the bucket url.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's the CSS folder's doesn't allow you to access the files inside. If you make the folder public, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Select all your files and folders, go to actions tab and then select make public to allow objects to access one another.